# parse text without explicit endtag

Tags: antlr

**The problem** of parsing a dictionary-entry (see examples below) is based on 
not having explicit start- and end-tags but:

- the end-tag of one element is already the start-tag of the following element
- or: the start-tag is not a syntactical element, but it is the current parsing state (so it depends on what you have already "seen" in the inputstream)

**example 1**, simple entry:

```
wordWithoutSpace [phonetic information]
definition as everything until colon: example sentence until EOF
```

**example 2**, entry with multi-definition:

```
wordWithoutSpace [phonetic information]
1. first definition until colon: example sentence until second definition
2. second definition until colon: example sentence until EOF
```

**As I would say it in words or pseudo-code:**

```
dictionary-entry : 
     word = .+ ' ' // catch everything as word until you see a space
     phon = '[' .+ ']' // then follows phonetic, which is everything in brackets
     (MultipleMeaning | UniqueMeaning)

MultipleMeaning : Int '.' definition= .+ ':' // a MultipleMeaning has a number 
                                             // before the definition

UniqueMeaning : definition= .+ ':'
```

**I've tried the Lexer with gates** (antlr-version: 3.2)

```
@members {
  int cs = 0; // current state
  }

@lexer::header {
  package main;
  }

Word :
  {cs==0}?=> .+ ' ' {cs=1;}     // in this state everything until 
  ;                             // Space belongs to the Word, now go to Phon-mode

Phon :
  {cs==1}?=> '[' .+ ']' {cs=2;} // everything in brackets is phonetic-information
;                               // after you have seen this go to next state

MultiDef : 
  {cs==2}?=> Int '.' .+ ':' {cs=3;}
  ;

Def : 
  {cs==2}?=> .+ ':' {cs=3;}
  ;

fragment
Digit :
  '0'..'9';

Int :
  Digit Digit*;
```

**The TestLexer:**

```
import org.antlr.runtime.ANTLRStringStream;
import org.antlr.runtime.CharStream;
import org.antlr.runtime.Token;

public class TestLexer {


    public static void main(String[] args) {


        String str = "Word [phon]1.definition:";
        CharStream input = new ANTLRStringStream(str);
        DudenLexer lexer = new DudenLexer(input);
        Token token;
        while ((token = lexer.nextToken())!=Token.EOF_TOKEN) {
          System.out.println("Token: "+token);
        }
    }
}
```

**The problems I have:**

- I get the error-msg: line 1:0 rule Def failed predicate: {cs==2}?
- I don't know if this is even the right way to do?

I am stucked for about three days with this and am very thankful for any help and hints.

Thank you,
Tom

Comment: I think you'll need to explicitly handle line feeds in your grammar to be able to do this - otherwise you'll have difficulty with things like `2. second definition until colon: this is the 2. line `.